# cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'Employee'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to search through Employee records by ID. So first I search through the database then I run another function to get the image but I am getting this error:

> Error 33  The best overloaded method match for
>   'DocketViewer.GetDivDriverLicence(int, Employee)' has some
>   invalid arguments
>   Error 34  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Data.DataSet' to 'Employee'

There is the code to search for the employee:

```
 DataSet ds = Lookups.Employee.GetEmployee(Company.Current.CompanyID, JobID);
 int MainCount = 1;
 foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
 {
     foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
     {
         ulPODS.Controls.Add(GetLi("<a href=\"#DriverLicence-" + MainCount + "\">Driver Licence-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString() + "</a>"));

         tabsPOD.Controls.Add(GetDivDriverLicence(MainCount, ds)); //error here
         MainCount++;
     }
 }
```

Function to display image:

```
 protected HtmlGenericControl GetDivDriverLicence(int Count,  Employee em)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Image");
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Title");
    DataRow desRow = dt.NewRow();
    desRow["Image"] = em.DriverLicenseScanImage;
    desRow["ID"] = em.ID;
    desRow["Title"] = em.EmployeeNum;
    dt.Rows.Add(desRow);
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.ID = "Driver Licence-" + Count;
    FormView fv = new FormView();
    fv.ID = "FormViewDriverLicence-" + Count;
    fv.ItemTemplate = FormView.ItemTemplate;
    fv.ItemCommand += new FormViewCommandEventHandler(fv_ItemCommand);
    fv.DataBound += (sender, em) => { fv_DataBound(sender, em, "driverlicence"); };
    fv.DataSource = dt;
    fv.DataBind();
    div.Controls.Add(fv);
    return div;
}
```

Comment: your second parameter is calling for an `Employee` but you're passing it a `DataSet`....

Comment: If you keep reasking basically the same question, **don't expect people to answer if you keep deleting your question** after an answer was provided.

Comment: How is the DataSet supposed to be converted to Employee? Either put a conversion in the code adding to the tabsPOD so you are passing in an Employee object or change the HtmlGenericControl to take in a DataSet.

Comment: @JBKing OP asked the same question a few minutes ago, then it was `List<Employee>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be something like this, where you'll have to write the `GetEmployeeFromDataSet` function to do the conversion though I suspect this will compile:

```
DataSet ds = Lookups.Employee.GetEmployee(Company.Current.CompanyID, JobID);
int MainCount = 1;
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
  foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
  {
     ulPODS.Controls.Add(GetLi("<a href=\"#DriverLicence-" + MainCount + "\">Driver Licence-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString() + "</a>"));
     Employee emp = GetEmployeeFromDataSet(ds);
     tabsPOD.Controls.Add(GetDivDriverLicence(MainCount, emp));
     MainCount++;
  }
}
```

...

```
Employee GetEmployeeFromDataSet(DataSet ds) {
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  // convert the data from the ds into the newly made emp.
  return emp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is because your `GetDivDriverLicence(int Count, Employee e)` takes an `Employee` as its second argument, and you're passing it a `DataSet`:

```
tabsPOD.Controls.Add(GetDivDriverLicence(MainCount, ds)); // <--- ds is a DataSet, not an Employee.
```

The bigger question is: what are you trying to *do* with the `Employee` instance in your `GetDivDriverLicence(int Count, Employee e)` method?  Is it something you can do with just one field in the data set?  Do you have a method for building an `Employee` instance from a row in a data table?

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, here is an example of what you might add to your `foreach` loop:

```
var emp = new Employee((int) dr["ID"]);
emp.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
emp.Age = short dr["Age"];
tabsPOD.Controls.Add(GetDivDriverLicence(MainCount, emp));
```

Comment: But if I try pass Employee I get the error: 'Employee' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: You can't pass `Employee` because it's a type -- only an instance of that type.  Where is your `Employee` constructor?  Or builder method?

Comment: I have a constructor: public Employee(int ID)

Comment: Okay, then you need to call it for each row in the data table in your data set, and populate the appropriate fields from the values in the row, then you can pass that instance to your GetDivDriverLicence method.

Comment: In the foreach statements I can see it is returning the correct Employee record so how do I pass the instance to GetDivDriverLicence?

Comment: Your code doesn't show you using your Employee constructor.  I've updated my answer with some sample code.